# Filtering LiDAR data with las2las by scan angle range?

Tags: lidar, filter, las, lastools, angles

I am using `las2las` to filter .las data and I would like to filter the data between a scan angle of -15:+15; however the algorithm tells me the following: ?

> error bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted.

I using the following as my input:

```
las2las -i /home/user/input.las -o /home/user/output.las --keep-scan-angle -15-15
```

How do I filter between a negative and positive range? From -15 to +15?

Comment: Make sure you are using LAStools not libLAS

Answer (score 1):

See the examples on `las2las` [README](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt). The correct way to express this parameter is:

```
-keep_scan_angle -15 15
```

The full code would be:

```
las2las -i input.las -o output.las -keep_scan_angle -15 15
```

---

<sub>For filtering LiDAR data by scan angle with other software, refer to:</sub> <sub>[How to filter LiDAR data by scan angle?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115414/how-to-filter-lidar-data-by-scan-angle)</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work for me as I have already used `--keep-scan-angle '0'` and that works fine. However, when I put in a range, it does not work

Comment: It does not seem to like a negative range!!

Comment: Did you try exactly how it was written above, i.e., with one dash "-" before "keep" (not two), and with a white space between -15 and 15 (and without quotation marks)? It should have worked, but not sure you followed the example. If none of these previous suggestions solves your problem, you might want to report a bug/ask for assistance in the [LAStools forum group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/lastools). @user1655130

Comment: Yep and it givesd me an error:unrecognised option '-keep_scan_angle'. I'm using it through the Linux command line.