# How complete are the Fusion tools in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, lidar, las, fusion

How complete are the Fusion tools in QGIS? I have them installed and (vaguely) working, but there are only about ten of them. Is the idea of having just a few tools available, that one can use LAStools for the other functions (say, format conversion)?

Also, is there a tool for canopy heights as las or shp, rather than grid?

Further, some of the Fusion tools run and create output. Others start running for a while and quietly die. Is there somewhere that error messages accumulate in QGIS?

Comment: Have you seen this guide? (http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) Hopefully others will advise if it still does not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is what I used to get lastools installed.  But it doesn't help much with the fusion functions -- if you don't want the "free" lastools to degrade your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How complete are Fusion tools in QGIS?

Fusion has 39 command line tools total (in version 3.3). In QGIS (2.12.2), there are 13 Fusion tools connected and available with GUI interface. They are:

```
CanopyMaxima, CanopyModel, Catalog, ClipData, CloudMetrics, Cover, CSV2Grid, FilterData, GridMetrics, GridSurfaceCreate, GroundFilter, MergeData, TinSurfaceCreate.
```

Therefore, currently it is 33.3% (13/39) complete in QGIS.

> Is there a tool for canopy heights as las or shp, rather than grid?

Yes, there is: `ClipData`. See: [Normalizing point cloud data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112587/normalizing-point-cloud-data/112618#112618).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while, but at the time I was concerned I'd installed them improperly or simply couldn't find some, not knowing QGIS all that well.