# Exporting ground returns (.las) from classified point cloud?

Tags: dem, export, lidar, classification, las

I have lidar data that is classified as several categories (water, ground etc.).

I need to open this lidar data in some software (it will be great if it would be a open source software) and delete a couple of them to leave only ground category.

Afterwards I have to export this data as *.las format again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the open-source [liblas](http://www.liblas.org/) tools for this. The command is,

```
las2las --keep-classes 2 -i input.las -o output.las
```

To do many files, use a loop.

```
for f in *.las;
do
    las2las --keep-classes 2 -i $f -o $(basename $f .las)_gnd.las
done
```

These commands are, of course, for linux, unix or OSX. liblas is also available for Windows through [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

Answer (score 1):

I used SAGA for the evaluation of my LIDAR data and some easy processing.

Go to `tool libraries` > `Import/export` > `LAS`. When you import the LAS data using `Import LAS Files` you can select the import of existing classifications (this should be your categories). Unfortunately, my LIDAR data don't have categories so I can't try it myself.

You can select points using `tool libraries` >`Shapes` > `Point Clouds` > `Point Cloud Reclassifier / Subset Extractor`.

If you want to save this selection as LAS data, you need to export it as LAS file using `Export LAS Files` (`right click` > `save as` saves the file automatically in the SAGA file format .spc).

[Here](http://geostat-course.org/system/files/pc_processing_with_saga.pdf), you'll find a tutorial about processing LIDAR data with SAGA.

Answer (score 1):

With [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html), the command line to be used is `ClipData` together with the switch `/class`.

It can clip las data according to the return classification and within specific area of interest.

The generic command line would look like this:

```
ClipData /class:2 InputSpecifier SampleFile [MinX MinY MaxX MaxY]
```

`/class:2` is because the required category is ground, which the standard classification is equal 2.

In [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112587/normalizing-point-cloud-data/113125#113125), I provided a detailed example about how to use the command line `ClipData`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Create a project folder somewhere. Mine is C:\GossanHill.
2. Put your .las files in there.

**Get the LASTools**

The programs we need don’t really need to be installed, just saved at a convenient location.

3. Get LASTools from [rapidlasso](https://rapidlasso.com/LAStools/).
4. Open the Lastools.zip file. Navigate to the bin folder. Copy these files to your project folder: `las2las.exe`, `las2txt.exe`, `lasinfo.exe` and `laszip.exe`. These programs are all free, open source, LGPL licensed software.

**Running the LASTools**

5. Open the Windows command prompt:Win + X then select Command prompt
6. Navigate to the project folder: CD C:\GossanHill.

What I did here was open the directory via `Total Commander` and ran cmd from there. Then you are already in the necessary directory.

7. Type a command, such as lasinfo Merged.las

I needed class 2 points and I ran `las2las.exe -i in *.las -keep_class 2`, but there are a lot of variations in the function.

```
las2las -i *.las -utm 13N
las2las -i *.laz -first_only -olaz
las2las -i *.las -drop_return 4 5 -olaz
las2las -latlong -target_utm 12T -i in.las -o out.las
las2las -i in.laz -target_epsg 2972 -o out.laz
las2las -set_point_type 0 -lof file_list.txt -merged -o out.las
las2las -remove_vlr 2 -scale_rgb_up -i in.las -o out.las
las2las -i in.las -keep_xy 630000 4834500 630500 4835000 -keep_z 10 100 -o out.las
las2las -i in.txt -iparse xyzit -keep_circle 630200 4834750 100 -oparse xyzit -o out.txt
las2las -i in.las -remove_padding -keep_scan_angle -15 15 -o out.las
las2las -i in.las -rescale 0.01 0.01 0.01 -reoffset 0 300000 0 -o out.las
las2las -i in.las -set_version 1.2 -keep_gpstime 46.5 47.5 -o out.las
las2las -i in.las -drop_intensity_below 10 -olaz -stdout > out.laz
las2las -i in.las -last_only -drop_gpstime_below 46.75 -otxt -oparse xyzt -stdout > out.txt
las2las -i in.las -remove_all_vlrs -keep_class 2 3 4 -olas -stdout > out.las
las2las -h
```

8. When you’re done, type exit

The output is: `your_las_1.las` as ground points.

Answer (score 0):

lasground.exe in the LASTools mentioned above. This can be run from command line prompt very cleanly.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I will be great if someone give me a clue how to do this in LASTools e.g. QGiS or ARCGiS. Is it option where I can just delete choosen categories or check some of these and export this data as *.las format?