# ArcPy filter and export LAS dataset

Tags: arcpy, export, las, point-cloud

Building upon [ArcPy IDW interpolation with LiDAR point cloud data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463081), suppose I want to select certain classes in the las file and then export the final output in its original format (.las), how do I do that?

I have seen a similar question at [Exporting ground returns (.las) from classified point cloud?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155030) but it does not solve my problem.

```
   # Create the LAS dataset layer
    lasd_layer = arcpy.management.MakeLasDatasetLayer(las_dataset, "LASD_Layer", class_code=[4, 5])
    
   # Save the LAS dataset layer to a new LAS file
    arcpy.management.ExtractLas(lasd_layer, output_las)
```

Comment: What about that doesn't solve your problem? Does it not create output LAS files? Are the class codes not restricted to class 4 and 5?

Comment: The suggestions involve working with other software that I am not familiar with. I need suggestions working with arcpy, to modify the last line of code.

Comment: The last line looks fine in isolation, your first parameter is a filtered LAS dataset and the 2nd should be a folder that already exists... so, what is the problem? Do you get error messages? Is there no output? Are all classes included? Are the output files unreadable?

Comment: There are no files saved in the output folder. `AttributeError: module 'arcpy.management' has no attribute 'ExtractLas'`

Comment: That's because it's not a management tool but a 3d tool: arcpy.ddd.ExtractLas, with the documentation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/extract-las.htm - do you have the 3d analyst extension? if not the tool will be locked and you'll have to try LASTools or obtain a 3d analyst extension.

Comment: That indeed worked! Thank you for your input.