# Classifying LiDAR data to mid vegetation using LAStools?

Tags: lidar, classification, lastools

I want to classify LiDAR vegetation points in low and mid vegetation, using LAStools.

High vegetation is simple to get, using top of canopy (first return), but how about low vegetation, and mid? Following ASPRS standards they are class 3 and 4, respectively. How could I separately isolate these classes using LAStools, in order to create DEMs from them?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49066/classifying-lidar-data-with-lastools; but not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lasheight](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasheight/) to classify points at different intervals above ground, assuming you have already classified ground points.  For example 0-1 meter above ground -> low veg, and 1-6 meter above ground -> med veg.  The height values for these 2 classes vary from project to project, as there is no set rule.  You can use the -classify_between option to set your tolerances. See the [readme](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasheight_README.txt) for more details.

For example, to keep only points between 1 and 6 units above the
ground, and save out to 'mid_veg.las', enter the following command:

```
lasheight -i lidar.las -o mid_veg.las -drop_below 1.0 -drop_above 6.0
```

Comment: thanks for answering. It worked, i've just reclassified points into low-mid-high vegetation using lasheight. Now, how could I get only ground points and low vegetation points? (So eliminating mid and high ones?)

Comment: Do you mean extract select classifications to a separate point cloud? Or create a DEM from them?

Comment: Separate the point cloud, and I can interpolate in SAGA GIS, i. e.

Comment: @user66349 See my edited answer